# i am not able to iterate a json document in angular2

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

i have just started angular2, and got a problem. I am not able to iterate a json document in angular2.data is coming from backend i tried many ways, also used elipses (?) operator but not working for me. Please help
**i want to print name under area array**
[image: here's the json code]

Comment: whats the json object called?

Comment: Please, throw example code from the service, and component.

Comment: its is country.

Comment: export class NewsComponent implements OnInit {
  showCity=true;
  showCategory=false;
  country:any;
  constructor(
    private media:MediaService,
    private title:Title
    ) { }
  ngOnInit() {

    this.media.getCountryData().subscribe(data=>{
      if(data.success){
        this.country=data.data;
      }
    });
     
  }
}

Comment: service code is getting json only

Comment: Add it to your initial question and format it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your .ts code, try the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.country.length; i++) {
        for(let n = 0; n < this.country[i].area.length; n++) {
            console.log(this.country[i].area[n].name);
        }
    }
}
```

You should get a list of all the names in the console

Comment: the names might be different to what you use but the code is the same either way

Answer (score 0):

First get the json as a string; then simply call `JSON.parse(myJsonString)` and you have your json-object

If you meant anything else please clarify, as I (and obviously others too) don't find your question formualted 100% clearly (for example, add some code or what you have tried before)